# how to pass value to php thorough POST(Can i do this just with html and php)

Tags: php, html

```
<div id="navigation">
       <ul>
         <li><a href="?id=0")><em>Home</em></a></li>
         <li><a href="?id=2")><em>Login</em></a></li>
         <!-- <form method="POST" onclick="form.submit();"> -->

         <select name="state">
         <option value="Genre">Genre</option>
         <option value="Crime and Drama">Crime and Drama</option>
         <option value="Drama and Romance">Drama and Romance</option>
         <option value="Sci-Fi">Sci-Fi</option>
         <option value="Action">Action</option>
         <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
         <option value="Adventure/Fantasy">Adventure/Fantasy</option>
         <option value="Action/Adventure/Fantasy">Action/Adventure/Fantasy</option>
         <option value="Action/Sci-fi/Thriller">Action/Sci-fi/Thriller</option>
         </select>
         <!--<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="listsubmit"  id="sub"> -->

         <li><a href="?id=3")><input type="submit" value="submit" name="listsubmit"></a></li>

         <li><a href="?id=1")><em>Contact us<em></a></li>
```

What i am trying to do here is take selection from dropdown menu and pass that value through $_POSt to my sql select statement and include that movies.php file in div content.

but unfortunateky i am not finding a way to pass var to php file .doesn't know y my $post is not working .Please guide me how to submit my form what should i menntion in action field since it is my nav.php div navigation. i select one option and pass that to movies.php which takes selected option and include that php in div content based on id value for example: this is my content.php

```
<?php 
        $id= isset($_GET['id'])? $_GET['id'] :0;
          if($id=="1"){
            include 'Store.php' ;
          }
          else if($id=="2"){
            include 'Login.php'; 
          }
          else if($id=="3"){
              include 'movies.php';       
}
```

Please advice!

Comment: your php is using $_GET not $_POST. They are not the same. Which do you wish to use. Search online for definitions of each if you are unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your select and form like this.

```
<form method="POST" action="?id=3">
     <select name="state" onchange="this.form.submit();">
         <option value="Genre">Genre</option>
         <option value="Crime and Drama">Crime and Drama</option>
         <option value="Drama and Romance">Drama and Romance</option>
         <option value="Sci-Fi">Sci-Fi</option>
         <option value="Action">Action</option>
         <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
         <option value="Adventure/Fantasy">Adventure/Fantasy</option>
         <option value="Action/Adventure/Fantasy">Action/Adventure/Fantasy</option>
         <option value="Action/Sci-fi/Thriller">Action/Sci-fi/Thriller</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

Form action needs for sending GET variable id. Inside movies.php now you can use $_POST['state']

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery AJAX request. You can pass values return content and show it.